# Implementing interface with just one class or more classes

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract

Maybe its answer is obvious for most of you  but I am a bit confused when implementing an interface.

Should  “just one implementation class” implement “the complete set of methods”? 
Forex:

```
public class CCSImplementation implements CCS {

    public void addComment (int submissionId,int customerId, String comment, Date date)   { }

    public void addGeneralComplaint (int submissionId, int customerId, String description, Date date)  { }  
        and other methods…..}
```

Or
-  More implementation classes such as

```
public class Comment implements CCS {
    public void addComment() {}    
}
```

and

```
public class GeneralComplaints implements CCS {
    public void addGeneralComplaint(){}    
}
```

implement the interface part by part taking into account of related methods? (---I got error when implement like these)

Since a reference says

> One or more classes can implement  that interface...

as I said I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is `abstract`, you don't have to implement all/any of the methods:

```
public abstract class Comment implements CCS {
    public void addComment() {}
    // addGeneralComplaint() is implied as abstract    
}
```

Depending on your need, it would be perfectly valid to define such a class, where *some* of the methods are implemented, but subclasses are left to implement the rest of the interface's methods.

Comment: Say I have 20 methods to be implemented:

Comment: public abstract class Comment implements CCS {

Comment: should contain 20 methods where some of them implemented and the rest are implied as abstract?

Comment: @serb if the class is abstract, it doesn't have to contain any methods or the implemented interfaces

Comment: I will use your suggestions in my upadated project design. Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW I meant **of** the implemented interfaces, not *or*. Bad eyesight and using iPhone to type :/

Answer (score 2):

When a non-`abstract` class implements an interface it **must** provide implementations of **all** the exposed by the interface methods.

If we have an `abstract class A`, it can implement an interface without providing method implementations of the interface-exposed methods, since all of them are abstract by default. But when this class is subclassed by a non-`abstract` class `B`, the subclass **must** provide the implementations of the interface-exposed method signatures.

Comment: abstract classes don't have to

Answer (score 0):

class Comment should extends Class GeneralComplaints

or

class GeneralComplaints should extends class Comment..

Answer (score 0):

If it turns out that you are using an abstract class then you don't have to use everything. From my understanding you only want to implement something if you plan on using the provided methods. It was explained to me that an interface s provided so that the user doesn't forget to use methods in their class. Hope this helps.